# Binding в UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Цель: сделать таблицу, в которой данные будут отображаться постранично.

Создал `UserControl`. 
Не могу понять как привязать свойства, которые непостоянны и высчитываются. К примеру, свойство `PageCount` отвечает за количество страниц в таблице и если пользователь укажет, что на одной странице может выводиться 50 строк, то это свойство нужно пересчитать. В моем коде значение этого свойства вообще не отображается.

Подскажите, как правильно привязывать такие свойства в `UserControl`?

---

**UPDATE**

Попробовал сделать VM и прибиндить к её свойствам `DependencyProperty`, как указано в этом [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21851139/6641468), но безрезультатно. Свойство `PageCount` по-прежнему не высчитывается и не отображается.

VM:

```
public class PagedDataGridVM : BaseVM
{

    private int _pageCount;
    private int _rowsPerPage;
    private IList _itemsSource;

    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get { return _itemsSource; }
        set
        {
            _itemsSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public int RowsPerPage
    {
        get { return _rowsPerPage; }
        set
        {
            _rowsPerPage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public int PageCount
    {
        get { return (ItemsSource.Count % RowsPerPage == 0) ? ItemsSource.Count / RowsPerPage : ItemsSource.Count / RowsPerPage + 1;}
    }
}
```

PagedDataGrid.cs:

```
    public partial class PagedDataGrid : UserControl
{
    public IList OnePageItems { get; set; }
    public PagedDataGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        userControl.DataContext = new PagedDataGridVM();
    }
    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);}
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IList), typeof(PagedDataGrid));


    public int RowsPerPage
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RowsPerPageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowsPerPageProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowsPerPageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RowsPerPage", typeof(int), typeof(PagedDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(100));

}
```

PagedDataGrid.cs.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.Controls.PagedDataGrid"
         x:Name="userControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Test.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="vm:PagedDataGrid">
        <Setter Property="RowsPerPage" Value="{Binding RowsPerPage}"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=ItemsSource}" >
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="vm:PagedDataGrid">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ItemsSource}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" 
          x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0" 
                x:Name="btnBegin"

                Content="Begin" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                x:Name="btnPrev"
                Content="Prev" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="1" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Button Grid.Column="3" 
                x:Name="btnNext"
                Content="Next" />
        <Button Grid.Column="4"
                x:Name="btnEnd"
                Content="End" />
        <Separator Grid.Column="5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="6">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="1"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding PageCount, StringFormat=of {0}}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действуйте по паттерну MVVM. Ваши свойства вынесите во ViewModel.
PageCount можно привязать следующим образом

```
<Label Grid.Column="7" Content="{Binding PageCount}" />
```

не забудьте задать DataContext для view

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Чтобы view подхватывала измененные свойства используйте MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

ну или делайте биндинг так

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=PageCount}
```

есть еще такой вариант, нужно задать имя контролу:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Name="This">
```

и использовать биндинг так:

```
{Binding ElementName=This, Path=PageCount}
```

Еще вариант, устанавливаете DataContext для родительского контрола

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" >
        <Label Grid.Column="7"     
    Content="{Binding PageCount}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: DataContext самого контрола лучше бы не менять - в некоторых сценариях его могут поменять "снаружи".

Comment: Лучше выставлять DataContext для элемента, который вложен непосредственно в UserControl.

Comment: {Binding ElementName=This, Path=PageCount}, так работать не будет. Правильный способ {Binding ElementName=This, Path=DataContext.PageCount}

Comment: @S.Kost я проверял, работает. вы видимо пропустили эту строчку <UserControl 
    x:Name="This">. Работать не будет ваш вариант, если не задать datacontext

Comment: @user2455111, где по вашему находится PageCount? во VM или в code-behind usercontrol?

Comment: @S.Kost как указал автор в code-behind usercontrol

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Согласен, добавлю в ответ

Comment: @user2455111 нее, если устанавливает его для Label - пропадает весь смысл. Я имел в виду установить DataContext для какого-нибудь Grid.

Comment: А как взаимодействовать во ViewModel со свойствами зависимости, которые есть у UserControl?

Comment: @user2455111, То есть если у меня в VM будет лежать свойство `PageCount`, которое вычисляется на основании количества элементов в таблице, то как VM узнает об этих элементах? Свойство зависимости `ItemsSource` ведь располагается не в VM.

Comment: @maxwell про dependency посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291518/inotifypropertychanged-vs-dependencyproperty-in-viewmodel Про количества элементов в таблице так же как и остальные свойства. Биндинг может работать в две стороны (смотря как его задать OneWay, TwoWay) И любое свойство элемента, можно присвоить свойству во viewModel

Comment: @user2455111, Посмотрите, пожалуйста, обновление вопроса. Весь код приложил. Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

Comment: @maxwell Вы пишете <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=ItemsSource}" >. Но у userControl нет свойства ItemsSource. Так же вы не задали DataContext.ни для UserControl ни для родительского элемента, поэтому ваша View не видит ViewModel

Comment: @user2455111, `DataContext` задан в конструкторе, `ItemsSource` также задан свойством зависимости. `VM` как раз-таки видна, с этим проблем нет. Но я не могу понять как мне задать свойство `PageCount`, которое нужно высчитывать на основании количества элементов. В текущем виде оно отказывается работать.

Comment: @maxwell вот тут наработки выложил https://ufile.io/b5b3e

Comment: @user2455111, Но как при таком подходе задавать `ItemsSource` извне, т.е. в `MainWindow.xaml`? Для этого мне и служили свойства зависимости, Вы же просто убрали их. Коллекция, к которой привязывается таблица не статична, постоянно обновляется и подгружает данные (парсер сайта) и я не могу перенести её в VM юзерконтрола.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50121/discussion-between-user2455111-and-maxwell).